# Fluctuations of the center of mass of a confined fluid?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, computational-physics

Consider a fluid at thermal equilibrium confined between two fixed parallel walls along the $x$-direction and with periodic boundaries in the $xy$-directions.

Without the walls, the momentum of the fluid is strictly zero because only the forces between the fluid particles are there, and therefore the center of mass should strictly not move. By adding the two walls the fluid is allowed to exchange momentum with the walls via collisions of the fluid particles, which makes fluctuations of the center of mass of the fluid possible.

What is the magnitude that we should expect for the fluctuations ?

For a classical molecular dynamics simulation of a Lennard-Jones fluid phase I have analyzed this question by calculating the fluctuation magnitude of the velocity of the center of mass, i.e the standard deviation of the center of mass velocity. In the data, the standard deviation of the velocity of one particle is as one expects from a Maxwell-Botzmann distibution  $\sqrt{<(v_{z})^{2}>}=\sqrt{\frac{k_{B}T}{m}}$. But the standard deviation of the particle averaged velocity (i.e the center of mass velocity $V_{z}=\frac{1}{N}\sum^{N}_{i=1}v^{i}_{z}$) turns out to be the following $\sqrt{<(V_{z})^{2}>}=\sqrt{\frac{k_{B}T}{mN}}$.

I found this result from my data and also data from previous works (PhysRevE.87.030101 by Siboni / Phys. Rev. 109, 1464 by Lebowitz / Phys. Rev. 187, 275 by Bruch) but I still do not understand the reason of the accuracy of the estimation $\sqrt{<(V_{z})^{2}>}=\sqrt{\frac{k_{B}T}{mN}}$. More precisely, this estimation means that the velocities of all particle are independent Gaussian random variables and therefore the standard deviation of the mean is just a linear combination of the standard deviations of all particles.

But why should the velocities be not correlated ? In a fluid phase it makes more sense to me to expect highly correlated velocities. Could you explain this point ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At equilibrium, if you believe Gibbs statistical mechanics, you expect the velocities to be uncorrelated since the kinetic part of the hamiltonian is just the sum of the kinetic energies of your particles:

$$H_k=\sum_i p_i^2/2m$$

However, the correlation you talk about will appear in the spatial part of your hamiltonian.
So, to be more explicit, a liquid is strongly correlated spatially (check, radial correlation function, it dictates how much you expect a particle to be close to an other one), but not correlated in term of velocities (on average you don't expect two particles to go everytime in the same direction or in opposite directions).

This was the equilibrium stat mech view. In kinetic theory, the situation is a bit more complex. You may have heard the term "molecular chaos". This is an assumption, firstly made by Boltzmann that assumes that velocities before a collision are uncorrelated. That is, when two particles collide, we can assume that they forgot everything about their past and their previous collisions. This assumption holds true in a lot of cases (except maybe in very very dense system, with the so called ring collisions or in non-equilibrium matter such as granular gases) and is well verified numerically. By assuming that you can recover the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution from the Boltzmann equation. Note however that, assuming that two velocities are always uncorrelated and that colliding particles are uncorrelated (in term of velocities) is not the same thing.