# Virial theorem for momentum fluctuations

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, virial-theorem, fluctuation-dissipation

In the paper https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.109.1464 Lebowitz attempted to derive an estimation of the magnitude of center of mass momentum fluctuations in the presence of external confining potential (i.e walls). He considers $N$ classical particles interacting via a pair potential $U(x_{i}, x_{j})$ subject to confining potential (thought of as walls) $V(x_{i})$, thus from

$\dot{p_{i}} = - \sum_{j} \partial_{x_{i}}U(r_{ij}) - \sum_{j} \partial_{x_{i}}V(x_{i})\tag{1}$

he arrives (after several clear, simple and understandable steps) at the relation

$\frac{<P^{2}>}{2M} = \sum_{ij} <x_{i}\partial_{x_{j}}U(x_{j})>\tag{2}$

where <> indicates the time average and $P$ indicates the center of mass momentum. Then he mentions the equivalence of time averages and phase space average but writes without further arguments the following equation

$\frac{<P^{2}>}{2M} = \int dx_{1} x_{1}\partial_{x_{1}}U(x_{1}) + \int \int dx_{1} dx_{2} x_{1}\partial_{x_{2}}U(x_{2})\rho(x_{1}, x_{2})\tag{3}$

I struggle to understand the step from (2) to (3) and I would appreciate hints. A further question is how to use equation (3) to derive the relation explicitly derive $\sqrt{<(V_{z})^{2}>}=\sqrt{\frac{k_{B}T}{mN}}$ that is mentioned in the appendix of the paper.
To add more context, my interest is in finding estimations of the fluctuations of center of mass momentum in systems such as classic particles forming liquid or gas and confined between walls (i.e exchanging momentum with the boundaries). This is asked in more detail here [Fluctuations of the center of mass of a confined fluid?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/788526/fluctuations-of-the-center-of-mass-of-a-confined-fluid)

Comment: There is probably a typo in (3), the density of numbers $\rho(x_1)$ is omitted. It appears that averaging over the Gibbs distribution is sufficient to obtain (3) from (2).

Comment: You mean $\rho(x_{1})$ should be in the first integral ? Yes that might be (the typo comes from the paper). But supposing we have Gibbs distribution, how can we derive equation (3) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will only consider the initial question about formula (3). Let $w_N(x_1,\ldots,x_N)$ be the $N$-particle probability density function of the Gibbs distribution. The explicit form of this function is not relevant for this discussion. We only need to use its symmetry property: the function $w_N$ does not change under any permutations of the coordinates of pairs of particles $x_i \leftrightarrow x_j$. Let us also define the number density $\rho(x_1)$ and the pair density $\rho(x_1,x_2)$ as follows
$$
\rho(x_1) = N\int dx_2\ldots dx_N\ w_N(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N),
$$
$$
\rho(x_1,x_2) = N(N-1)\int dx_3\ldots dx_N\ w_N(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N).
$$
Now consider the average value of the quantity on the right side of equality (2). We have
$$
\overline{\sum_{i,j}x_i\partial_{x_j}U(x_j)} = \sum_{i}\overline{x_i\partial_{x_i}U(x_i)} + \sum_{i\neq j}\overline{x_i\partial_{x_j}U(x_j)},\tag{I}
$$
where
$$
\overline{x_i\partial_{x_j}U(x_j)} = \int dx_1\ldots dx_N\ w_N(x_1,\ldots,x_N)\ x_i\partial_{x_j}U(x_j).
$$
Due to the symmetry of $w_N$ and the definition of densities, we further have
$$
\overline{x_i\partial_{x_i}U(x_i)} = \overline{x_1\partial_{x_1}U(x_1)} = 
\frac1N \int dx_1\ \rho(x_1)\ x_1\partial_{x_1}U(x_1)\tag{II}
$$
and for $i\neq j$
$$
\overline{x_i\partial_{x_j}U(x_j)} = \overline{x_1\partial_{x_2}U(x_2)} = 
\frac1{N(N-1)} \int dx_1dx_2\ \rho(x_1,x_2)\ x_1\partial_{x_2}U(x_2)\tag{III}
$$
Thus, the first sum on the right side of equality (I) has $N$ terms of the form (II), and the second sum has $N(N-1)$ terms of the form (III), from here we get what we need
$$
\overline{\sum_{i,j}x_i\partial_{x_j}U(x_j)} = \int dx_1\ \rho(x_1)\ x_1\partial_{x_1}U(x_1) + \int dx_1dx_2\ \rho(x_1,x_2)\ x_1\partial_{x_2}U(x_2).
$$

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Further comment on the second part of the question would appreciated.

Comment: @YoussefMabrouk I don't understand how to use equation (3) to get the relation for $\langle V_z^2\rangle$, but I'll probably argue later why the relation should have the form it does.